# htaccess is not redirecting

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well, i want the user to enter `localhost/$value` so it will redirect to `localhost/pirsum/index.php?page=g&link=$value` but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?$    [NC]
RewriteRule .*       index.php?page=g&link=%1 [L]
```

I tried to enter `localhost/` AND `localhost/pirsum` and both ended on 404 Not found site.

Now, thats the only part of my website that i need to use htaccess, so i dont want the whole site to redirect, just that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pirsum/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=g&link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it looks like it redirect me to the WAMP main page and not to the index.php

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and your index.php?

Comment: they both on `127.0.0.1/pirsum/` folder

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot, its working great now. so just so i'll know, when i'll upload the site on the host, i'll need to change `RewriteBase /pirsum/` to `RewriteBase /` right?